# Best practice for location of a Query

Tags: vb.net, architecture, datagridview

I'm writing in VB.net 4.0 and using SQLExpress 2008 R2.  In a DataGridView, I would like to display (no edits) data coming from multiple tables in my database. A second Grid (different data, still multiple tables) will need to allow editing and saving of data.

I understand creating a View in the database and using that as a source for the DataGridView.  I also assume that there are ways to query and create a data source for the Grid totally within my VB program.  Would someone explain the consequences and implications of the different approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look into LINQ to SQL for your data calls. It would be prudent for you to create a data access layer class that performs all of your data calls separate from any UI architecture you have. This allows you to maintain the data calls within the code but separated from any display logic.

Putting your queries into SQL server as views or stored procedures simplifies some of your immediate code within the application, but over time stored procedures and views become harder to maintain. Unless you have massive data load and optimization requires stored procedures, I'd recommend you investigate the usage of LINQ for making quick, atomic data calls.

Comment: +1 although I'd add that since SQL Server 2005 there's usually no performance advantage to using stored procs anyway. Plus, you can use LINQ with procs.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the good old Stored Procedure. Write one SP, getting data for each gridviews.